# JSON parse problem, when website is hosted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to show all news on my website. The page where the news is shown has filtration, sorting and server side pagination.

On load of that page I call AJAX that send data to pagination.php, and in response I call function which displays the news. Here is the problem; this code works on `localhost` with no problem, but not when I publish to the hosted website.

AJAX is throwing a `parseerror` exception  and I don't know how to solve it. This code works on localhost.

Does anyone know hot to solve this problem? Note, the code syntax is 100% correct, the `printNews` function is less important I gave it just to have better look in situation.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: `pagination.php`,
  method: "get",
  dataType: "json",
  data: data,
  success: result => {
    printNews(result.news, result.dates, result.limit)
  },
  error: (xhr, exception) => {
    console.log(xhr)
  }
}
})

function printNews(news, dates, limit) {
  let html = "";
  let rb = limit * 2 + 1;
  var i = 0;
  
  for (n of news) {
    html += `<div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="row news-lg mx-0 mb-3">
        <div class="col-md-6 h-100 px-0">
          <img class="img-fluid h-100" src="img/${n.src}" alt="${n.alt}" style="object-fit: cover;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 d-flex flex-column border bg-white h-100 px-0">
          <div class="mt-auto p-4">
            <div class="mb-2">
              <a class="badge badge-primary text-uppercase font-weight-semi-bold p-2 mr-2 category-btn" data-view="${n.category_id}" href="#">
                ${n.name}
              </a>
              <p class="text-body mb-0"><small>${dates[i]}</small></p>
            </div>
            <a class="h4 d-block mb-3 text-secondary text-uppercase font-weight-bold" href="index.php?page=single&single=${n.news_id}">
              ${n.title.length > 15 ? n.title.substring(0,15)+"..." : n.title}                                              
            </a>
            <p class="m-0">
              ${n.content.length > 130 ? n.content.substring(0,130)+"..." : n.content}                                                      
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between bg-white border-top mt-auto p-4">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>`;
    rb++;
    i++;
  }
  
  $('#insert-news').html(html);
```

```php
session_start();
header("Content-type: application/json");

if(isset($_GET['btn']))
{
  include "functions.php";
  include "../connection/database.php";

  try
  {
    $limit = $_GET["limit"];
    $filter = isset($_GET["category"]) ? $_GET["category"] : null;
    $sort = isset($_GET["sort"]) ? $_GET["sort"] : null;

    $news = allNews2($filter, $sort, $limit);
    $pages = newsNumber($filter)->number;
    $dates = [];
    foreach($news as $n)
    {
      array_push($dates, date("l, j M Y", strtotime($n->date)));
    }

    echo json_encode([
      "news" => $news,
      "pages" => $pages,
      "dates" => $dates
    ]);
    http_response_code(201);
  }        
  catch (PDOException $exception)
  {
    http_response_code(500);
  }
}
else
{
  http_response_code(404);
}

function allNews2($filter, $sort, $limit = 0)
{
  global $conn;
    
  $criteria = "";
  if ($filter != null && $filter != 0)
  {
    $criteria = "WHERE c.category_id = :cat ";
  }

  if ($sort != null && $sort != 0) {
    if ($sort == 1) 
    {
      $criteria.="ORDER BY n.date DESC ";
    }
    else
    {
      $criteria.="ORDER BY n.date ASC ";
    }
  }

  $query = "SELECT * FROM img i INNER JOIN news n ON i.img_id = n.img_id INNER JOIN category c ON n.category_id = c.category_id ".$criteria."LIMIT :limit, 4";
  $prepare = $conn->prepare($query);

  $limit = ((int)$limit) * 4;
  $prepare->bindParam(":limit", $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  if ($filter != null && $filter != 0)
  {
    $prepare->bindParam(":cat", $filter);
  }
  $prepare->execute();

  $result = $prepare->fetchAll();
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: Open up your browser's developer console and look at the response in the Network tab. See if there's anything wrong with the response there.

Comment: it is not the error, server responded with http response 200, I checked it already

Comment: That's the response *code*. You need to look at the details of the response itself. It should have the json, but may have some extra characters throwing it off.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, there is nothing in respone. How can I solve it? It's just strange because this works in local

Comment: You'll need to do some troubleshooting to find out where it's going and what's happening. At a guess, `$_GET['btn']` is not set, so it's not entering the if block.

Comment: @BrajanMarković if there is no response, the error lies in your PHP. Would advise you check your PHP Logs to see if any error is being generated. If none, then maybe your SQL Query is generating no results.